# Why getline() doesn't accept a constant istream?

Tags: c++, constants, iostream, getline, istream

Basic question here, I'm trying to learn the basic of iostream.

I'm told to build a function reading lines of a *const istream&*. i.e. validateFile(const istream& is)

I figured out that I can't use the function getline() with a *const istream&* as first argument. I'm wondering why. I thought I was just reading the istream, does the function getline() alters it?

Is it possible to get information from a constant stream at all?

Comment: It reads a line out of the stream, so it changes its state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of a stream is to read some data from it sequentially, each time advancing its internal pointer. By advancing this pointer you change the stream object. You can't read from `const` streams (unless you `const`-cast them but that's something you shouldn't do).

**EDIT:** Actually we don't care if the actual stream object hidden behind `istream` interface uses some "internal pointers" or not. To be precise, the important thing is that the stream changes its state when you read it, because the next time you read it, you get a different result (you read the next thing from the stream). And if you're given a `const` object, it means that you're not supposed to change its state.

Also, there's a reason why you can't just get the data from the stream and not change anything. In case of file streams it's that the next thing you want to read from the stream might not even be in the memory, stream object may have to read it from the disk first, update its buffers, etc. (**EDIT:** But that doesn't change externally visible state of the object, so actually it's not a good argument. Read about `mutable` keyword to find out more.)

Comment: @MemyselfandI You're right, istream is just an interface and whether actual file stream uses some kink of pointer to its buffer or not is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get data from a `const` stream, but you need to do the reading through the streambuf class that it manages:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    const std::istringstream strm("Const stream");
    std::streambuf* buf = strm.rdbuf();

    char c;
    while ((c = buf->sbumpc()) != EOF)
        std::cout << c;
}
```

Comment: This should be considered a **BUG IN THE SPECIFICATION**. -1 to counter the silly upvotes.

Comment: Hi, @JanHudec, I disagree. It's a BUG TO HAVE CONST STREAM! (imho). Have a nice day :)

Comment: @jrok: It obviously does not make any sense to have a const stream, but when you have const stream, it shouldn't let you get non-const pointer to it's buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline()` (as well as other I/O functions) set the underlying stream state to indicate errors during parsing or formatting. This is why the streams cannot be `const`-qualified. Moreover, the `width()` of the stream is reset after certain operations.